# replace all occurrences of string

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I'm trying to replace all occurrences of the string:

```
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-for-accessibility-issues-a16f6de0-2f39-4a2b-8bd8-5ad801426c7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
```

with `xyz`. This is to be done for all files under the current directory.

I used the following command:

```
find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/https\:\/\/support\.office\.com\/en\-us\/article\/Check\-for\-accessibility\-issues\-a16f6de0\-2f39\-4a2b\-8bd8\-5ad801426c7f\?ui\=en\-US\&rs\=en\-US\&ad\=US/xyz/g';
```

But it did nothing. I think the way I'm escaping the special characters is wrong. How do I correct it?

Right now, I'm prefixing every non-alphanumeric character with `\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed default uses BRE, you escaped some chars, which gave its special meaning in BRE, e.g., `\?` doesn't mean literal `?`, instead, it means, `zero or one occurrence`

You should adjust your escapes.. or use delimiter other than `/` in sed.

```
...sed 's@http://foo?bar@xyz@g`
```

Comment: @anukul you should take a look what are special chars in BRE.  I think in your example, you just need escape the `.` (dot)

Comment: Okay, and how does changing the delimiter help?

Comment: @anukul the last line code in my answer is the example, I picked `@`. it is by default `/`, you have to escape all slashes, I think you have many in a web url.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another delimiter like `~` and avoid escaping most of the symbols in `sed` command.

Try this command:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's~https://support\.office\.com/en-us/article/Check-for-accessibility-issues-a16f6de0-2f39-4a2b-8bd8-5ad801426c7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US~xyz~g' '{}' +
```

Even `?` doesn't need to be escaped in BRE as it matches literal `?`.

Comment: Okay, this worked. But which all characters do I need to escape now?

Comment: You need to escape `[ * . ] ^ $` etc

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is okay, check out [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
$ cat ip.txt 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-for-accessibility-issues-a16f6de0-2f39-4a2b-8bd8-5ad801426c7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

$ perl -pe 's|\Qhttps://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-for-accessibility-issues-a16f6de0-2f39-4a2b-8bd8-5ad801426c7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US|xyz|' ip.txt 
xyz
```

And use `exec` option instead of xargs

```
find -type f -exec perl -i -pe 'print "$ARGV" if s|\Qhttps://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-for-accessibility-issues-a16f6de0-2f39-4a2b-8bd8-5ad801426c7f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US|xyz|' {} +
```

Comment: What if `|` is part of the URL?

Comment: you'll have to escape it.. `echo 'as|asd' | perl -pe 's|\Qs\|a|xyz|'`

Answer (score 0):

tried it it didnt work

sed 's@wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/plugins/share-this/css/style.css,wp-content/plugins/wp-to-twitter/css/twitter-feed.css,wp-content/themes/yourgarden/style.css,wp-content/plugins/cleverness-to-do-list/css/cleverness-to-do-list-frontend.css,wp-content/plugins/cleverness-to-do-list/css/jquery-ui-fresh.css?wp-content/css/all.css@'
sed: -e expression #1, char 344: unterminated `s' command